# How to override the @section in MVC Razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Please help me to fix this issue. I have two files BaseLayout.cshtml and the second one is ExtendedLayout.cshtml file for overriding the base content of HTML CSS.
I need to run the extended section of extendedLayout.cshtml file if same section is present in override otherwise base would work. Same as OOPS override concept.

**Base Layout CSS Code**

```
@section HeadCssSection {
   @*Base Layout CSS *@
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/BaseCSS")
   @RenderSection("HeadCssSection")

}
```

**Extended Layout CSS Code**

```
@section HeadCssSection {
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/ExtendedCSS")
    @RenderSection("HeadCssSection") 
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on "I need to run the extended section of extendedLayout.cshtml file if same section is present"

Comment: Here is what I need to do 
If CSS Code available in base and extended then extended code should be run 
If CSS Code available in base and not in extended then base code should be run

Comment: @Umashankar did you solve the problem?

Comment: I have solved that issue

Comment: How did you solve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isSectionDefined()` like following

```
@if (!IsSectionDefined("HeadCssSection")) { 
    RenderSection("HeadCssSection") 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Base layout, write the code like this.

```
@section HeadCssSection {
   @if (IsSectionDefined("HeadCssSection"))
   {
       @RenderSection("HeadCssSection")
   }
   else
   {
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/BaseCSS")
   }
}
```

Define this HeadCssSection in extended layout so that it will take extended layout code. And if you want to run the code of base layout, then put the code in else condition.